In a WebExtension's background.js script, how can I access values from manifest.json?
Suppose I'm maintaining a WebExtension, with a Manifest V2 file. My extension has a background.js script which sets all sorts of things up. Now, I want to access arbitrary key-value pairs from my extension's manifest.json file, within the background.js script.
Is this possible? If so, how do I do that?
Note: In case it matters, the app is Thunderbird; and I'm not really maintaining a WebExtension, but that's complicated and out of scope.

The solution is the same as for one of the existing answers.

@woxxom: So, I just noticed that question... but - the solution is not exactly the same, since chrome doesn't work in other apps. Shall I leave this question as is, or shall I adapt it to focus on the difference?

chrome is available in Thunderbird as well as in Firefox. It contains the callback-based version of the API compatible with chrome extensions, including chrome.runtime.getManifest.

@woxxom: Ok, flagged this as a dupe then.

Depending on the application your background script is running in, you can use either chrome.runtime.getManifest() or browser.runtime.getManifest().
Specifically, this works in a thunderbird background
(async function () {
  let manifest = browser.runtime.getManifest();
  console.log(manifest.name); // will log the name of your WebExtension
  // ... rest of your code
})();

